# How to use mutate function in iteration

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to search a list of motifs in a data frame. Here I am attaching sample datasets and code.

```
Gene_and_Promoter <- tibble::tribble(
                     ~Gene,                                                ~Promoter,
                   "Gene1", "AGTCACGTGCGTGCATACGTGCAAATTGGGCGTACGTGGCTATCTCAACTATCH",
                   "Gene2",  "AACGTGGCGTGGCAGTGCACGTGCCAGTTGTCCCGCAGTGTGCATACTACTCT",
                   "Gene3",   "ACTGGCTACGTGCTGCAATGCGTGCGTAGTGCGTACCAAAGTTAAACCGGCG",
                   "Gene4",   "GCAATACGTGCAAGTGCGTGTACGTGCGTGATGTCGTACGTAACCGGCCGGT",
                   "Gene5",     "ATACGTGCGTCGTACGTGCGTACTAATACATACATCATAATTTAAACCCG",
                   "Gene6",          "GGGGGAATCTCGTTCCTACGTCAAGGATAGATGCTGATAGTCGTA"
                   )
Motifs <- tibble::tribble(
             ~MOTIF,
            "CGTGC",
           "GGAATA",
             "CCAG",
            "CGTA"
           )


 Gene_and_Promoter %>% 
  mutate(CGTGC = vcountPattern("CGTGC",DNAStringSet(Gene_and_Promoter$Promoter))) %>% 
  mutate(GGAATA = vcountPattern("GGAATA",DNAStringSet(Gene_and_Promoter$Promoter))) %>%
  mutate(CCAG = vcountPattern("CCAG",DNAStringSet(Gene_and_Promoter$Promoter))) %>% 
  mutate(CGTA = vcountPattern("CGTA",DNAStringSet(Gene_and_Promoter$Promoter)))
```

The above code delivers the desired output (Motif presence in promoter).

Can I optimize the above code by reducing the number of times to use mutate ? (Probably by iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possibility similar to @det's answer, but within the tidyverse...

```
library(tidyverse)

pat <- c("CGTGC", "GGAATA", "CCAG", "CGTA")

# set names so that map_df() keeps them...
lpat <- as.list(pat) %>%
  set_names(., pat)

dd <-
  Gene_and_Promoter %>%
  mutate(across(Promoter, ~map_df(lpat, ~ vcountPattern(., DNAStringSet(Promoter))))) %>%
  as.list() %>%
  bind_cols() %>%
  full_join(Gene_and_Promoter, .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without insight in function `DNAStringSet`. Maybe try something like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

vec <- DNAStringSet(Gene_and_Promoter$Promoter)
Motifs <- c("CGTGC", "GGAATA", "CCAG", "CGTA")

setDT(Gene_and_Promoter)
Gene_and_Promoter[, (Motifs) := map(Motifs, ~vcountPattern(.x, vec))]
```